# How do I use lambda expression to make comparison?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, oop, lambda

I have an HW question that needs to go through a list of the airport and find the best and worst on-time record using the lambda expression.

The list contains two columns Airport Name and Delay Departure.

So if the Delay Departure > 0 we count 1 delay else we count on-time.
How can I do that using lambda expression?

```
for x in data:
    if airport != x.Orig:
       continue
    delay = list(map(lambda x: x.Orig = airport and x.DepDelay > 0, data))
    print(len(delay))
    ontime = list(map(lambda x: x.Orig = airport and x.DepDelay == 0, data))
    print(len(ontime))

    perf = ontime / (ontime +delay)

    if perf < minPerf:
       minAiport = airport
       minPerf = perf
    if perf > maxPerf:
       maxAirport = airport
       maxPerf = perf
```

I expect the lambda expression able to identify the name of the airport and its delay and ontime frequency. Then I can do max and min to find out the best and worst performance of which airports.

For example, airportA is the best, perf:
airportB is the worst, perf:

Comment: Can you add example data?  Not sure what you mean by *"The list contains two columns"*.

Comment: Do you mean  delay = list(map(lambda x: x.Orig == airport and x.DepDelay > 0, data)). You used one equal sign for the logical comparison

Comment: Also, whats wrong with your current code?

Comment: Sorry... I mean the file contains two columns (name of airport and delay time). I have to go through the file to find the best and worst performance of the airport and its performance.

Answer (score 0):

Per your code, I assume your input data looks like this:

```py
class Data:
    def __init__(self, airportname, depdelay):
        self.Orig = airportname
        self.DepDelay = depdelay

data = [
        Data('airportname1',3),
        Data('airportname2',0),
        Data('airportname3',2),
        Data('airportname1',1),
        Data('airportname2',4),
        Data('airportname3',0),
        Data('airportname2',0),
        Data('airportname1',0),
        Data('airportname3',1),
        Data('airportname4',3),
        Data('airportname2',2),
        Data('airportname1',0),
        Data('airportname4',3),
        ]
```

Please try below solution:

```py
result = {}
for x in data:
    if x.Orig not in result:
        result[x.Orig] = {'delay':0, 'ontime':0}
    if x.DepDelay > 0:
        result[x.Orig]['delay'] += 1
    else:
        result[x.Orig]['ontime'] += 1

maxperf = 0
minperf = 1
maxairport = []
minairport = []
for airport, r in result.items():
    a = r['ontime']
    b = r['delay']
    perf = a/(a+b)
    print("Airport Name: {}, ontime: {}, delay: {}, perf: {}".format(airport,a,b,perf))
    if perf > maxperf:
        maxperf = perf
        maxairport = [airport,]
    elif perf == maxperf:
        maxairport.append(airport)

    if perf < minperf:
        minperf = perf
        minairport = [airport,]
    elif perf == minperf:
        minairport.append(airport)

print("best performance airport: {}, performance: {}".format(maxairport, maxperf))
print("worst performance airport: {}, performance: {}".format(minairport, minperf))
```

The output based on my input are:

```
Airport Name: airportname1, ontime: 2, delay: 2, perf: 0.5
Airport Name: airportname2, ontime: 2, delay: 2, perf: 0.5
Airport Name: airportname3, ontime: 1, delay: 2, perf: 0.3333333333333333
Airport Name: airportname4, ontime: 0, delay: 2, perf: 0.0
best performance airport: ['airportname1', 'airportname2'], performance: 0.5
worst performance airport: ['airportname4'], performance: 0.0
```

Comment: I'm happy to help. @EzrealReal